# nltk library error showing punkt not downloaded

Tags: nltk

Resource punkt not found.
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

> > > import nltk
> > > nltk.download('punkt')

For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

this showing in my code terminal and i dont know how to download so if anyone can help me how to download this please help me

Comment: To download resources from `nltk` you need to `import nltk` and execute `nltk.download(module_name)` and it will be downloaded at the root path and check whether the user has access or not if issue is persisting.